# Error: Could not find a valid gem installing rails on mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to install rails version `5.0.0.1` using the command below

```
gem install rails -v 5.0.0.1
```

but I get this error

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (= 5.0.0.1), here is why:
        Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

How can I get past this error and install rails version 5.0.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow as steps below:

1. `gem sources -a http://rubygems.org`
2. `gem install rails -v 5.0.0.1`

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you could try to replace in your Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

with

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
```

so that the SSL connection error dissipates. This snippet of code is located at the top of your Gemfile

Or, you can simply run `gem sources -a http://rubygems.org` so that your gems (including the rails 5.0.0.1 gem) are downloaded via http rather than https

Although, if you want to use the encrypted download via SSL, follow [this guide](https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88) on GitHub that leads you through the process of installing a certificate to trust RubyGems.org